# Counting the oldest arrears

Tags: excel, countif

I have a list of supplier arrears and need a count of total part arrears, but I only want to count a suppliers' oldest arrear.

| Supplier | Part | August | September | October |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12345 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| A | 12346 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Desired Count |  | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I have tried countif on the columns but do not know how to exclude the newer arrears from the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
=LET(range,$C2:$E3,
minCol,BYROW(range,LAMBDA(row,MIN(IF(row>0,COLUMN(row))))),
SUM((C2:C3>0)*(COLUMN(C2:C3)<=minCol)))
```

in C4 and pulled across

[image]

or this should spill:

```
=LET(range,$C2:$E3,
minCol,BYROW(range,LAMBDA(row,MIN(IF(row>0,COLUMN(row))))),
BYCOL(range,LAMBDA(col,SUM((COLUMN(col)<=minCol)*(col>0)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `COUNTIFS()`.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$3,"<"&MAX($B$2:$B$3),C2:C3,">0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With several suppliers you can apply this formula which is filled across range C8:E9 in the example.

=IF(SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($C$2:$E$5,$A$2:$A$5=$B8),COLUMN(A$1)))=0,0,COUNTIF(INDEX($C$2:$E$3,,XMATCH(TRUE,BYCOL(FILTER($C$2:$E$5,$A$2:$A$5=$B8),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c)>0)))),">"&0))

[image: Counting the oldest arrears]